# Are all LinkedIn member id's numbers?

Tags: linkedin-api

I can't seem to find a definitive answer on this, but I'm wondering whether the member ID for a LinkedIn user is always made of numbers. The documentation seems to indicate that that is the case, but I don't see a description that explicitly states that the member ID is *only* numbers.

Can anyone confirm this and link to the documentation that says this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the Member Id that is returned via the API when making a GET https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id), then that value can be made up of numbers or letters.